# Python relative import in package breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Here is my project structure:

```
Project
   main.py
   myPackage/
      subfolder1/
         __init__.py
         script11.py
         script12.py
      subfolder2/
         __init__.py
         script2.py
```

In `main.py`:

```
from myPackage.subfolder2 import script2.py
```

In `script2.py`:

```
from ..subfolder1 import script12.myFunction
```

In `__init__.py` from `subfolder1`:

```
from script11.py import *
```

and the code breaks at that import and throws the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script11'
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `from .script11 import *` will fix your error. Pretty sure there will be more errors, but you should be able to figure those out.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by @Kacper Floriański, changing

```
from script11.py import *
```

to

```
from .script11.py import *
```

solved my issue